# Выделение текста в word

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

Привиден пример выделения текста *"с"* и *"по"* строки, а требуется *"с"* и *"до конца"*

```
W.ActiveDocument.Range(Start := 10, End := 40).Select;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если *"до конца"* = "До самого конца":

```
Procedure SelectFromPositionToEnd(startPosition: integer);
begin
  W.Selection.Start := startPosition;
  W.Selection.End   := W.ActiveDocument.Characters.Count; // последний символ в документе
end;
```

Если *"до конца"* = "До конца предложения":

```
Procedure SelectFromPositionToEdnOfSentence(startPosition: integer);
const
  WdSentence = 3; //значение для перехода к следующему предложению
begin
  w.Selection.Start := startPosition; //поставили сюда курсор
  w.Selection.Move(WdSentence, 1);    //передвинули до следующего предложения
  w.Selection.Start := startPosition; //растянули выделение до начального символа
end;
```

Если *"до конца"* = "До конца строки", то тоже что и во втором случае, только заменить первый параметр в Move
с

```
WdSentence
```

на

```
Wdline = 5 //значение для перехода к следующей линии (строке)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
```

Comment: Это вместо 40 добавить?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @Makine Нет, добавить НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННО ПОСЛЕ. И выделение это не по строкам, а по символам.

Comment: Это немножко не синтаксис Delphi.

Comment: Синтаксис и вправду не delphi... кто может на delphi перевести?

Comment: Да-а-а, дела... W.Selection.EndKey(wdStory, wdExtend); ... Или может W.Selection.EndKey(Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend); ... или у тебя позднее связывание, и тебе ещё значения констант найти и подсказать?

Comment: @Akina вы человек опытный, многое знаете, многие вещи для вас просты и очевидны. SO это место где менее опытные могут спросить вашего совета. Пожалуйста, относитесь с пониманием к тому, что не все всё знают и не всем всё так же очевидно. Постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы и более терпимо относится к вопросам и уточнениям. А то время, что вы потратили на перепалку, вполне можно было потратить на составление развернутого ответа.

Comment: Тут простой принцип. Надо записать в ворде макрос и посмотреть содержимое. Ну а потом тупо вызовы функций загуглить, что и как было сделано. На разных языках есть польно разных примеро, можно и на delphi найти.